# WCF Test client, is it possible to get the app to remember previously provided values?

Tags: wcf

I really loved the web based test form of asmx, because it used the browsers built in functionality to remember previously provided parameters. It was also much easier to startup for a debugging session.

Is it possible to get the WCF test tool to remember previously supplied values, or is it too primitive?

Is there another tool I should be using to get the same convenience back that was in the days of asmx that Microsoft decided to drop from the newly updated WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) you can take a look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Comment: Its Java, isn't it very slow?

Comment: I am using it happily every day and don't think it is slower than a typical windows application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into TDD to solve your problem instead of writing a test client.  In TDD, you write unit tests before you write your business logic.

A possible scenario would be that your test is written with the values of interest.